# Detect if there is any Confirm MessageBox opened

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

I'm using the WebBrowser object in a secondary form to open url, and when the web is loaded, get the  and close that form, but I have some troubles.

I have a Timer() with 8 seconds, and if the form still alive after 8 seconds, the form is forced to close.

The WebBrowser is a poor navigator, so I get in some webs an "alert()" telling that I need to upgrade my navigator. When an "alert()" is loaded by the WebBrowser object, it is displayed in my app like a MessageBox, so I need to close first that message and then close my navigator form.

For that, I did this:

In the main form:

```
    int cont = 0;

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cont += 1;            

        if (cont == 8)
        {
            var formularios = Application.OpenForms;

            for (int i = formularios.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (formularios[i] != this)
                {
                    formularios[i].Dispose();
                }
            }

            t.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Enabled = true;

        p = new FormNavigator();

        p.Navigate("URL HERE");
        p.ShowDialog();

    }
```

It works for me with the "alert()" functions, but some webs use the "confirm()" function, and it opens a form with OK/Cancel buttons... and the Application.OpenForms doesn't detect it.

Do you know any way to detect those "confirm" dialogs from .NET?

Regards.

**Update**

I have this properties in my WebBrowser object:

```
    navigator.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    navigator.AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;
    navigator.IsWebBrowserContextMenu = false;
    navigator.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

And I have handled the NewWindow event like this:

```
    private void navivator_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no Built-in function  do do this but you can supress all  dialogs messages using  this

//hides all its dialog boxes that originate from the underlying ActiveX control, not just script errors

```
   webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: Hello Julie, thanks for your answer. I have that property set to true, but it doesn't work for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by implementing IDocHostShowUI

```
int IDocHostShowUI.ShowMessage(IntPtr hwnd, string lpstrText, string lpstrCaption, int dwType, string lpstrHelpFile, int dwHelpContext, out int lpResult)
{
    // return handled
    //  S_OK        Host displayed its UI. MSHTML does not display its message box.
    //  S_FALSE     Host did not display its UI. MSHTML displays its message box.
    //
    if (this.CloseOpenDialogs == true)
    {
        lpResult = 0;
        return S_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        lpResult = 0;
        return S_FALSE;
    }
}
```